# Is there an extensible way to initialize a struct from an array in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, list-initialization

```
struct SomeStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

void main() {
    std::array<int, 4> arr {1, 2, 3, 4};
    SomeStruct someStruct { ??? }; // <------ Initialize with arr? (Ideal would be {arr})
}
```

As seen in the code example, is there some shortcut to initialize someStruct with arr?
Instead of resorting to:

```
    SomeStruct someStruct {arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]};
```

Comment: What if replace `SomeStruct` with `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: Wouldn't that incur dynamic allocation?

Comment: It will. But if you have an array, why do you need `SomeStruct` with the same data? Your problem is not clear to me.

Comment: If you know, that the memory is correct aligned and the same size, you could use something like memcpy, but I wouldn't use this solution

Comment: The simple answer is no, there is no "quick hand" way to accomplish this. Yes, you could gamble on a union, or blast a memcopy. For me, the best alternative would be a helper that sets up a `SomeStruct` as you're have in your second snippet, and letting elision take it's rightful place. A proper ctor for `SomeStruct` seems legit, imho. You only have to do it *once*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `std::apply` to create a parameter pack and use that in the initializer:

```
auto someStruct = std::apply([](auto&&... args){return SomeStruct{decltype(args)(args)...};}, arr);
```

You can put this in a function to use it comfortably:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
constexpr T make_from_tuple_list_init(A&& a) {
    return std::apply([](auto&&... args){return T{decltype(args)(args)...};}, std::forward<A>(a));
}
```

Then use it as

```
auto someStruct = make_from_tuple_list_init<SomeStruct>(arr);
```

This requires C++17 and `#include<tuple>`, but can be implemented in earlier C++ versions (with some more effort) as well. Also in C++17 this is guaranteed to use copy elision, so there will be only one `SomeStruct` constructed. Before C++17 some move constructions might be involved (although compilers were already permitted to and did implement return value optimization with the same effect).

`std::apply` also has the benefit that it works with every type that implements `std::get` and `std::tuple_size`, meaning that it will work for example with `std::array`, `std::tuple`, `std::pair` and other user-defined types with that interface.

One might want to make two versions of this function, one that uses `T{...}` as above and one that uses `T(...)`, so that one is able to choose between list-initialization and direct-initialization.

However, the `T(...)` version has been implemented in the standard library since C++17 as `std::make_from_tuple`. In C++20, aggregate initialization will also work with parentheses, so `std::make_from_tuple` will work for your case then directly.

---

For a C++14 implementation, take this example from [cppreference's page on `std::make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple):

> ```
> namespace detail {
> template <class T, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
> constexpr T make_from_tuple_impl( Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...> )
> {
>   return T(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
> }
> } // namespace detail
>
> template <class T, class Tuple>
> constexpr T make_from_tuple( Tuple&& t )
> {
>    return detail::make_from_tuple_impl<T>(std::forward<Tuple>(t),
>        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>{});
> }
> ```

and replace `std::tuple_size_v<...>` with `std::tuple_size<...>::value`.

This is for the `T(...)` version. You would need to replace `T(...)` with `T{...}` to get the `T{...}` version I implemented above.

Comment: @YSC It is equivalent to `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)`. It is just a functional style cast of `args` (lvalue) to its declared reference type (lvalue/rvalue).

Comment: Yes I see it now. Tk

Answer (score 1):

You can define a constructor taking a pair of iterators. Sometimes simplicity wins over flexibility.

```
#include <array>

struct SomeStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

    template<class InputIt>
    SomeStruct(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
    {
        if (begin != end) a = *begin++;
        if (begin != end) b = *begin++;
        if (begin != end) c = *begin++;
        if (begin != end) d = *begin++;
    }
};
```

Demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e235a8022b048ac

Answer (score -2):

You can use one of the Memory Transfer functions. {memcpy, CopyMemory}

this is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   array<int,4> ar = {1,2,3,4};

   struct myStruct
   {
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      int d;
   };

 myStruct stc;

memcpy(&stc, ar.data(), sizeof(stc));


cout << "My struct elements are: " << stc.a << " - " << stc.b << " - "<< stc.c << " - " << stc.d << endl;
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: include `<cstring>` instead of the C header, and get rid of that `using namespace`.